# Find the most common term in multiple sets Java?

Tags: java, optimization, merge, set, time-complexity

I understand the principle of finding the most common term among an array of sets by only including items contained in both i.e.

```
[5,1,3]
[4,2,3]
```

merge to return 3

However, If I want to know the most common item between sets that may not include any items or none of the most common item.

if I have:

```
[5,1,3]
[4,2,3]
[6,7,8]
```

I would still want 3 returned due to it being the most common item between the sets. Whereas merging sets would merely return nothing because 3 is not an element in one of the sets.

Anybody know a way of solving this with low-ish time complexity?

Comment: You should try to write some code first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would probably be to flatten those sets to their elements, count how many times each item appears, and save the one that appears most:

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(5 ,1, 3));
Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 2, 3));
Set<Integer> set3 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(6, 7, 8));

Integer commonItem =
    Stream.of(set1, set2, set3)
          .flatMap(Set::stream)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                              (Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long> comparingByValue().reversed())
          .findFirst()
          .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
          .orElse(null);
```

**Note:**
This solution produces a single element with the most occurrences. In order to support ties, you'll have to tweak it a bit.